# Tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists. Each list shows what a person has purchased by color and state. I want to find the difference between the two. The number of people in the two lists are not the same.

```
list1 = [{'Jeff':{'Red':(0.4, 'NY'), 'Green':(0.6, 'NJ'), 'Blue': (0.3, 'NJ')}}]
list2 = [{'Steve':{'Red':(0.2, 'NY'), 'Green':(0.8, 'NJ'), 'Black':(0.7, 'CT') }}]
```

The difference between `list1[0]` and `list2[0]` is `1.4`. It is calculated by color: Red( 0.2) + Green (0.2) + Blue (0.3) + Black(0.7). By state, the difference is NY (0.2), NJ(0.5 = 0.2 + 0.3) and CT(0.7).

I have been trying the following:

```
def diff(first, second):

diff = 0
templist = []

for color, purchase in first.items():
    other = second.get(color)
    if other is not None:
        diff += abs(purchase[0] - second[color][0])
        templist.append((first[color][1], diff))
    else:
        diff += purchase[0]
        templist.append((first[color][1], diff))


for color, purchase in second.items():
    other = first.get(color)
    if other is None:
       diff += purchase[0]
       templist.append((second[color][1], diff))

return diff, templist
```

How to get the desired output in a list below by the state for each person in `list1`? Thanks.

```
  Jeff  1.4  [NY, 0.2]  [NJ, 0.5]  [CT, 0.7]
```

Comment: Can you please show what did you try?

Comment: Thanks for adding your existing code.  What specifically do you need help with?  The current code returns an error, because if your function arguments are two lists, a list does not have an .items() attribute.

Comment: Hi ALexK, there is no error if you run diff(list(list1[0].values())[0], list(list2[0].values())[0]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the diff function in templist. You should append the current color difference and not the accumulated diff. Then, you should sum all the values which correspond to the same city.

It should be:

```
def diff(first, second):
    diff = 0
    templist = []

    for color, purchase in first.items():
        other = second.get(color)
        if other is not None:
            color_diff = abs(purchase[0] - second[color][0])
            diff += color_diff
            templist.append((first[color][1], color_diff))
        else:
            color_diff = purchase[0]
            diff += color_diff
            templist.append((first[color][1], color_diff))

    for color, purchase in second.items():
        other = first.get(color)
        if other is None:
            color_diff = purchase[0]
            diff += color_diff
            templist.append((second[color][1], color_diff))

    # Sum templist
    templist =  [
        (c, sum([v for c_in, v in templist if c_in == c]))
        for c in set([i[0] for i in templist])
    ]

    return diff, templist
```

Comment: Hi rafasan, thanks. the NJ value is 0.5 for this case. It is because that we get the abs difference by color first ,then add them up. Therefore, it is abs(green) + abs(blue) = 0.2 + 0.3. Your code gets 0.1 for this case.

Comment: Alright, I have edited my answer in order to work as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot rafasan.